# How to get node's depth in an HTML tree?

Tags: html, tree, html-agility-pack

I'm using HtmlAgilityPack to parse and analyze HTML pages, and I need to know the "depth" of each node - The distance from the `Body` node. Example (the "depth" attributes are only for illustration purposes):

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body depth="0"> 
    <div depth="1">
      <ul depth="2">
        <li depth="3">
          <p depth="4">foo</p>
        </li>
        <li depth="3">
          <p depth="4">bar</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to avoid the two obvious solutions:

- Scan the HTML tree (DFS, BFS, etc..), calculate the depth of each node, and store the values in a Dictionary, or similar.
- Calculate the depth of each node "on demand" by counting `node.ParentNode` until `body` is reached.

Is there a way to avoid these by somehow using the already existing data collected by HtmlAgilityPack on `Load`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking if there's a built in `NodeDepth` property or something like that? I'm pretty sure the answer is no, as calculating that for every node parsed by the library would create an overhead that would rarely be warranted. Since counting node depth is pretty easily done with some recursion, I don't think they'd include that per default.

Why do you want to avoid the obvious solutions?

Comment: As you noted yourself, it creates an overhead. recursion is easy to write, but hard on performance in my case (I've profiled it). 
I know there is no `NodeDepth` property, but still looking for something else that could help...

Comment: Ah, your hope is that the parser keeps this count somewhere usable, so you won't have to navigate the tree once more after parsing is done? Makes sense, but I'm inclined to say that this isn't possible unless you make changes to the library itself... which might be a feasible solution depending on how important this is.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, AgilityPack doesn't store the depth of nodes.

If you want to get the *depth* of **all** nodes, suppose, it would be easier to write e.g. a recursive method starting from the root node and increasing *depth* with a recursive call to the current node children.

As for the depth calculation for a single node you could use the `HtmlNode.XPath` property, and calculate the number of slashes(`/`) in this value. This will be the node depth. In your case you should calculate the `<body>` node's depth first, and then substract this value from the desire node's depth to get the *relative depth*:

```
var bodyDepth = doc.DocumentNode
    .SelectSingleNode("//body")
    .XPath
    .Count(c => c == '/');
var paragraphDepth = doc.DocumentNode
    .SelectSingleNode("//p")
    .XPath
    .Count(c => c == '/');
var result = paragraphDepth - bodyDepth;
```

This will give you `4`, but I'm not sure this is easier than iterate up through the `ParentNode` property.

Comment: how to do this in pure js?

Answer (score 0):

HtmlAgilityPack won't give the depth details. We can get it from XPath variable using count of '/' character as provided above. We don't need to traverse to the parent for getting the details.

```
 foreach (HtmlNode rootNode in document.DocumentNode.Descendants())
            {
                levels.Add(rootNode.XPath.Count(x => x == '/'));
            }
```

It should work.